# I'm trying to get а real traffic stats data. But, When i count `TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes()` for whole day its more than my data pack?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-trafficstats

eg. I have a 1.5 GB data pack. It gives the total sum of 2.0 GB or more than that .
any idea about how to get correct speed every second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats#getTotalRxBytes()) does not return your data pack value. It refers to the total received bytes (either wifi/mobile) since the last boot (turning ON phone). For mobile data, it will be [`TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats#getMobileRxBytes()). More importantly, these values get reset in every reboot of device.

> I have a 1.5 GB data pack. It gives the total sum of 2.0 GB or more
> than that .

The android system does not know anything about your data pack. You are adding it again and again. When you call `TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()` at a moment, it returns total mobile data received upto this moment since last boot. Following is an explanation. Hope this helps.

```
// Suppose, you have just rebooted your device, then received 400 bytes and transmitted 300 bytes of mobile data
// After reboot, so far 'totalReceiveCount' bytes have been received by your device over mobile data.
// After reboot, so far 'totalTransmitCount' bytes have been sent from your device over mobile data.
// Hence after reboot, so far 'totalDataUsed' bytes used actually.
long totalReceiveCount = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes();
long totalTransmitCount = TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
long totalDataUsed = totalReceiveCount + totalTransmitCount;

Log.d("Data Used", "" + totalDataUsed + " bytes"); // This will log 700 bytes

// After sometime passed, another 200 bytes have been transmitted from your device over mobile data.
totalDataUsed = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();

Log.d("Data Used", "" + totalDataUsed + " bytes"); // Now this will log 900 bytes
```

> any idea about how to get correct speed every second.

You cannot get actual speed this way. You can only calculate and show how much bytes have been received/transmitted in a second. All the speed meters in android do the same I think. Something like the following:

```
class SpeedMeter {
    private long uptoNow = 0;
    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    private ScheduledFuture futureHandle;

    public void startMeter() {
        final Runnable meter = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                long now = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
                System.out.println("Speed=" + (now - uptoNow)); // Prints value for current second
                uptoNow = now;
            }
        };
        uptoNow = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
        futureHandle = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(meter, 1, 1, SECONDS);
    }

    public void stopMeter() {
        futureHandle.cancel(true);
    }
}
```

And use like this:

```
SpeedMeter meter = new SpeedMeter();
meter.startMeter();
```

Although this code is not perfect, however it will suit your needs.

Comment: i used `TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()`. and counted it for 24 hours in the count variable to get one-day data usage but it gave me the wrong output.it gives more than my actual data pack. that's what I am saying.

Comment: Did you add it every time to your count variable? Like, `count += TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()`?

Comment: Yes I did the same

Comment: but it gives incorrect output. more data usage than my actual data pack

Comment: See the updated answer. Hope, this helps. You can also use any other threading utility if you want.